# Does minimum spanning tree exist with a non-connected graph?

Tags: graph-theory

I was thinking that Prim's algorithm won't work with a disjointed graph. But maybe it doesn't have to.

When we're asking to find the minimum spanning tree of a graph, is it implicit that the graph will always be connected?

Comment: Yes.  The graph must be connected.

Comment: For a disjointed graph you can't have a spanning tree. If you want a subgraph that spans the entire disjointed graph it's called a spanning forrest.

Answer (score 0):

Ya , you have to assume that because it is a minimum spanning **tree**. A Tree is directed, acyclic and connected graph. So if there are separate components in graph. You can form a forest(Collection of trees) of minimum spanning tree but it cannot be called as a single MST.